# If $A^3B-B$ is invertible then $BA-B$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I assume this is a simple proof but i'm stuck here.

I need to prove that if $A^3B-B$ is invertible then $BA-B$ is invertible.

So $A^3B-B=(A^3-I)B$  and then both $(A^3-I)$ and $B$ are invertible.

So I need to show that $BA-B=B(A-I)$ are both invertible.

I thought maybe I could somehow show that if $(A^3-I)$ is invertible then $(A-I)$ is invertible but I guess there's a simpler way to get there. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what is the factorization of $a^3-b^3$ for real numbers? When does such a factorization work for matrices?

Comment: "I thought maybe I could somehow show that if $(A^3-I)$ is invertible then $(A^3-I)$ is invertible" - well, that's clear anyway, right?

Comment: I meant $(A−I)$ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$A^3B - B = (A^3 - I)B; \tag 1$

thus the invertibility of $A^3B - B$ implies both $A^3 - I$ and $B$ are invertible.  Since

$A^3 - I = (A - I)(A^2 + A + I), \tag 2$

the invertibility of $A^3 - I$ yields the same for $A - I$ and
$A^2 + A + I$.  Since now $A - I$ and $B$ are invertible, so is their product

$B(A - I) = BA - B. \tag 3$

Comment: Very nice always your answers. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Hint $$A^3-I = (A-I)(A^2 + A + I).$$

Comment: It should be $I$ everywhere.